# R - Transposing portions of a data frame

Tags: r, reshape, transpose, reorganize

I have a .dbf file I exported from ArcGIS 10.1 and I need to reorganize the it. An example of the data is:

```
       V1               V2
40.000000000000000 41.000000000000000

40.000000000000000 42.000000000000000

41.000000000000000 40.000000000000000

41.000000000000000 42.000000000000000

41.000000000000000 43.000000000000000

42.000000000000000 40.000000000000000

42.000000000000000 41.000000000000000

42.000000000000000 43.000000000000000

43.000000000000000 41.000000000000000

43.000000000000000 42.000000000000000
```

I need the data in a format where there is only one row for each unique value in the first column, with all of the corresponding values from the second column now appearing in that row, for example:

```
  V1                   V2              V3                  V4
40.000000000000000 41.000000000000000 42.000000000000000

41.000000000000000 40.000000000000000 42.000000000000000 43.000000000000000

42.000000000000000 40.000000000000000 41.000000000000000 43.000000000000000

43.000000000000000 41.000000000000000 42.000000000000000
```

If anyone can help me with this problem I would appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can split up your data frame using the `split` function on the first column and the use `lapply` to extract your vectors:

```
dat = data.frame(X1=c(40, 40, 41, 41, 41, 42, 42, 42, 43, 43),
                 X2=c(41, 42, 40, 42, 43, 40, 41, 43, 41, 42))
res <- lapply(split(dat, dat[,1]), function(d) c(d[1,1], sort(unique(d[,2]))))
res
# $`40`
# [1] 40 41 42
# 
# $`41`
# [1] 41 40 42 43
# 
# $`42`
# [1] 42 40 41 43
# 
# $`43`
# [1] 43 41 42
```

Most would probably prefer to keep the data in this format, but you can also combine the list into a matrix, right-padding the vectors with `NA` values:

```
max.len <- max(unlist(lapply(res, length)))
do.call(rbind, lapply(res, function(x) { length(x) <- max.len ; x }))
#    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# 40   40   41   42   NA
# 41   41   40   42   43
# 42   42   40   41   43
# 43   43   41   42   NA
```

Comment: +1, nice demonstration of `NA` padding for equal length of rows

Answer (score 2):

You could also do this in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
  dat%>% 
  group_by(X1) %>%
  mutate(Time=seq_along(X1)) 
  %>%spread(Time,X2)
 #Source: local data frame [4 x 4]

 #X1  1  2  3
#1 40 41 42 NA
#2 41 40 42 43
#3 42 40 41 43
#4 43 41 42 NA
```

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially a `reshape` problem, but you don't have a "time" variable.

You can easily create a "time" variable as follows:

```
dat$time <- with(dat, ave(X1, X1, FUN = seq_along))
```

From there, use `reshape` from base R...

```
reshape(dat, direction = "wide", idvar="X1", timevar="time")
#   X1 X2.1 X2.2 X2.3
# 1 40   41   42   NA
# 3 41   40   42   43
# 6 42   40   41   43
# 9 43   41   42   NA
```

... or `dcast` from "reshape2"...

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(dat, X1 ~ time, value.var="X2")
#   X1  1  2  3
# 1 40 41 42 NA
# 2 41 40 42 43
# 3 42 40 41 43
# 4 43 41 42 NA
```

Comment: Both of your suggestions have gotten me almost there. Using reshape the data reformatted properly, but it only kept one time. I got the following warning message:


Warning message:
In reshapeWide(data, idvar = idvar, timevar = timevar, varying = varying,  :
  multiple rows match for time=1: first taken

Comment: Using reshape2 I received this error message: Error in unique.default(x) : unique() applies only to vectors. Both of my columns come back as TRUE when is use is.vector()

Comment: @user3769213, how similar is your actual data to this example data you shared? This approach should work if you can generate a "time" variable based on your grouping or "id" variable.

Comment: The example data is a portion of the actual data. The only changes I had to make to the code involved the name of the dataset and the column headings.